# How to pass a function as an argument to a ReactJS component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a reusable ReactJS button component and need help on how to 
pass a function to a component and then use it as a click event.  The click event on the button is not working.

Here is the code that will call the component:

```
export var MyPublicFunction = function (inArg: number) {
    alert(inArg);
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyButton name="My Button" clickFunction={MyPublicFunction(1)} >Button</MyButton>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Here it the component I'm trying to write:

```
interface myProps {
   name: string;
   clickFunction: any
}

class MyButton extends React.Component<myProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: myProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <button ref="btn1"  onClick={this.props.clickFunction} >
                {this.props.name}
             </button>
        </div>);
    } //end render.
} //end class.
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<MyButton name="My Button" clickFunction={MyPublicFunction(1)} >
```

The expression `MyPublicFunction(1)` is immediately invoked during evaluating of the containing expression. What you want is to provide a *function* to `clickFunction`:

```
<MyButton name="My Button" clickFunction={() => MyPublicFunction(1)} >
```

Note that you would get a type error if you had written something like this:

```
interface myProps {
   name: string;
   clickFunction: () => void;
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I just wish the syntax did not have to look so weird.

Comment: @Ryan Cavanaugh if `clickFunction` is an *optional* is this a right way `clickFunction? : () => void;` ?

Answer (score 4):

this method worked for me:

The parent:

```
 class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
   greet() {
    alert('Hello!')
   }
   render() {
      return (
       <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <Home greet={this.greet}/>
       </div>
     ) 
   }
}
```

The child:

```
interface Props {
  greet: () => void
}

export class Home extends React.Component<Props, State> {
 constructor(props: any) {
   super(props)
 }

 render() {
   return (
    <button className="btn btn-warn" onClick={this.props.greet}>Greet</button>
   )
 }
}
```